# IEFC452I Job not run

Tags: jcl

I want to know why my JOB not run...

```
//PAYMENT  JOB MSGCLASS=H
//STEP1    EXEC PGM=PAYMENT,REGION=1024K,
//              PARM=('CSQ1,CARD.PAYMENTS,<userID>.REPLY,<userID>',
//                    '245.00,"My Payment"')
//STEPLIB  DD DSN=<userID>.PART2.LOAD,DISP=SHR
//         DD DSN=WMQ.V6R0.SCSQLOAD,DISP=SHR
//         DD DSN=WMQ.V6R0.SCSQANLE,DISP=SHR
//         DD DSN=WMQ.V6R0.SCSQAUTH,DISP=SHR
//STDOUT   DD SYSOUT=*
//STDERR   DD SYSOUT=*
//SYSPRINT DD SYSOUT=*
```

It's just run when all parameters are in the same line like this:

```
//     PARM='CSQ1,CARD.PAYMENTS,<userID>.REPLY,<userID>,245.00,"My Payment"'
```

If I break the line my JOB not run, returning an error:

```
//     PARM=('CSQ1,CARD.PAYMENTS,<userID>.REPLY',
//           '<userID>,245.00,"My Payment"')
```

Error:

```
21.07.52 JOB03062  IEFC452I PAYMENT - JOB NOT RUN - JCL ERROR  955
```

...

```
STMT NO. MESSAGE                                                               
        2 IEFC621I EXPECTED CONTINUATION NOT RECEIVED                           
        3 IEFC605I UNIDENTIFIED OPERATION FIELD                                 
        4 IEFC605I UNIDENTIFIED OPERATION FIELD
```

Thanks!

Comment: If you google IEFC621I EXPECTED CONTINUATION NOT RECEIVED, you'll get a bunch of hits. This one looked useful http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=isg1OA19406. It's a good tool google...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have the PARM to far across to the right for a continuation (column 17). Try some thing like:

```
//STEP1  EXEC PGM=PAYMENT,REGION=1024K,
//       PARM=('CSQ1,CARD.PAYMENTS,<userID>.REPLY,<userID>',
//       '245.00,"My Payment"')
```

Contiuation must start in columns 4 through to 16 (see [JCL Continuation](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/zvm/v5r4/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.zos.r9.ieab100/jclexs.htm))